# Selectively load stimulus controller in Rails 7

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stimulusjs

Is there a way to selectively register a stimulus controller so it doesn't get registered on every page in Rails 7.

I have a stimulus controller `stripe_controller.js` that imports stripe-js:

```js
    import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js"
```

and this is causing stripe to generate an iFrame on every page of my site even when the controller is not connected.

My `app/javascript/controllers/index.js` is loading my controller:

```js
    import { application } from "./application"

    import StripeController from "./stripe_controller"
    application.register("stripe", StripeController)
```

Is there a way to dynamically register instead of including it in the `index.js` file?

Comment: its recommended to load it on every page to keep an eye on shifty behavior. but, maybe this will do it: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js#importing-loadstripe-without-side-effects

Comment: Alex - your suggestion also works, thanks!  To make this work with importmaps i had to change my pin from `pin "@stripe/stripe-js", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@stripe/stripe-js@1.54.1/dist/stripe.esm.js"` to `pin "@stripe/stripe-js/pure", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:@stripe/stripe-js@1.54.1/dist/stripe.esm.js"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found a solution in the ImportMap Documentation :| https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails#selectively-importing-modules.

Basically, you can move the register code from `app/javascript/controllers/index.js` to a new js file such as  `app/javascript/register.js`.

```
import { application } from "./controllers/application"

import StripeController from "./controllers/stripe_controller"
application.register("stripe", StripeController)
```

Then you need to pin it to `importmap.rb`

```
pin "register"
```

Then you need to yield it into the the header, so if you don't already have something like `<%= yield(:head) %>` in your application.html.erb layout then add it.  Now you can yield the register script on the ERB pages you need it like so:

```
<%= content_for :head do %>
    <%= javascript_import_module_tag "register %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This solution works but Alex's suggestion to use `stripe-js/pure` is the way to go for a Stripe integration.